# Calculating the time the concentration stayed above certain value in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to calculate the time the concentration stayed over 200. My simulated data frame has these columns:

```
df <- 
ID   TIME   CONC 
1     0      20
1     2      50
1     4      150
1     6      210
1     9      260
2     0      20
2     2      50
2     4      70
2     6      100
2     9      150
3     0      20
3     2      50
3     4      250
3     6      310
3     9      150
```

My thought was to add a `0,1` flag for `CONC >= 200` and then, for each individual, take the time difference for when the flag is 1.

```
#add flag
df$flag200 <- ifelse(df$CONC >= 200,1,0)
```

which gives:

```
df <- 
ID   TIME   CONC   FLAG
1     0      20     0
1     2      50     0
1     4      150    0
1     6      210    1
1     9      260    1
2     0      20     0  
2     2      50     0 
2     4      70     0
2     6      100    0
2     9      150    0
3     0      20     0
3     2      50     0
3     4      250    1
3     6      310    1
3     9      150    0
```

I need help in how to summarize the TIME differences for when the CONC flag is 1. For example, `tdif` for `ID==1` is `TIME==9 minus TIME==6` which is equal to `3`. The output should be something like this:

```
dfout <- 
ID   tdif
1     3
2     NA
3     2
```

Comment: preferably using dplyr as it allows me to summarize by different variables in the data set (i.e. suammarise by ID and other things) but I want to get the basic on how to do it by `ID`.

Comment: I would simply do `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[CONC > 200, diff(range(TIME)), by = ID]` without flags or anything, though this skips this  missing IDs. Or if you insist on `NA`s, could do `setDT(df)[, if(any(CONC > 200)) diff(range(TIME[CONC > 200])) else NA_integer_, by = ID]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `diff` on the indicator for the concentration being at least 200, you can identify all the starts and ends of time ranges of interest, summing the differences of those timestamps to get the total elapsed time:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(tdiff = sum(TIME[diff(c(CONC >= 200, 0)) == -1] -
                        TIME[diff(c(0, CONC >= 200)) == 1]))
#      ID tdiff
#   (int) (int)
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     0
# 3     3     2
```

Note that this code will work even in cases where there are multiple runs of at least value 200 for a given ID, and it will not count the time in between runs where the value dipped below 200.

Comment: Thank you. That is useful. I have another thing; can I add what day `CONC` started to be >=200 and add this to my output data frame? For the example above all are at Day1 but I have an extended time points for up to 21 days in my data.

Comment: @Amer you could just add `firstTime = min(TIME[CONC >= 200])` to the `summarize` call to get the first time the concentration exceeded 200. It's unclear to me how time maps to days, since you haven't provided any information about the day in your sample data.

Comment: Assuming the time is in hours. Yep, that make sense. Thanks!